How do I access the inner attributes inside JSON values, if the attribute name is unique for all data in BigQuery?
The following is the JSON format of one of the values
object{
    data{       
    menuMapping{}
    menuStructures{}
    menus{
        fc24304a-3c6f-43e3-b166-75ad588cc760        
          createdAt :   2021-02-06T10:59:40.609Z
          displayOptions        {3}
          currencyCode  :   USD
          disableItemInstructions   :   false
          isMenuV2  :   true
        entities        {3}
          combinationsMap   :   null
          customizationsMap{
    -- ... and so on

The attribute name fc24304a-3c6f-43e3-b166-75ad588cc760 is unique to the data in the particular cell, and for all the other cells too. Which wildcard character should I use in my SQL Query to access?
I tried enclosing the query in backticks like this and without it too
SELECT tablename.data.menus.<and then I'd get stuck here>.createdAt
I tried putting using $ % and * symbols but to no avail. Nowhere did I find anything related to this in the docs. Please if anyone could link the particular doc I'll be very grateful.
My issue is very similar to what this fellow user is facing but I'm using BigQuery, the other user JavaScript.
EDIT: Silly me! In the dataset there was another key-value pair that had these unique values stored. Thanks to anyone who tried to come up with answers, though :)
